# Dynamic constant definition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm defining a constant in an initializer in Rails using the following syntax:

```
MyModule.const_set('MYCONSTANT','foobar')
```

It works, if I start a console and write

```
MyModule::MYCONSTANT
```

I receive foobar as expected.

The problem is, when I try to call it in a Model the constant is not there.

Where should D dynamically define my constant that it can be available as well in my models?

If I statically define it in my lib/mymodule.rb it works but I would like to define some constants at runtime.

Comment: You made a typo: MY_CONSTANT vs MYCONSTANT. Is it just an error in the question, or that's the problem in your code?

Comment: typo in the question, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe autoloading in development mode is the problem?

Your model class is recreated for every request, so you would need to create the constant again and again.

The problem would just disappear in production mode. You may turn off the autoloading in development mode, but this will force you to restart the server after every change in your code.

See config/environments/development.rb: `config.cache_classes = false` (change to true).

Answer (score 22):

if you want to keep `config.cache_classes = false`,
you can put

```
MyModule.const_set('MYCONSTANT','foobar')
```

into following block in application.rb:

```
config.to_prepare do
MyModule.const_set('MYCONSTANT','foobar')
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I've stumbled on this as I was trying to do "dynamic constants".

My goal is to be able to use a specific database entry as a constant. (Once inserted, the line will never change on a specific instance but ids can be different on different instances).

I came up with a solution that could apply to this case depending on why you're trying to have dynamic constants. Here's an example in my usecase but it's fairly easy to replace the attribute definition by something else.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.MY_CONST
    @my_const ||= MyModel.find_by(code: 'my_const_code')
  end
end
```

And here's how i tested it:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MyModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "mymodel constant defined" do
    assert_equal MyModel.find_by(code: 'my_const_code'), MyModel.MY_CONST
  end
end
```

Comment: This isn't a constant, it's a method with an uppercase name

Comment: Indeed. As explained in my message, this is an alternate solution that could fit the need behind wanting dynamic constants.